# How can I parse fetch JSON return and put elements in to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using the Javascript fetch api I have an HTML page as follows:

```
<body>

<div> <button onclick="github();">Get</button> </div>

<div id ="resp">    </div>
</body>
```

and a Javascript function as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function github() {
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users/KrunalLathiya')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
    const obj = JSON.stringify(data)
    document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = obj["html_url"]
    })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
   }
  </script>
```

the returned json prints fine in the console but in the resp div it appears as "undefined" or, trying a different method object[Object]

How can I loop through the json return and print the elements on the html page? Then, by extension, with a Python Flask app? Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't stringy it, data is already in JSON format.  Try `data.html_url`...

Comment: @SwetankPoddar: `data` is *not* 'already in JSON format", `response.json()` has converted it to an `Object`. "JSON format" is just a `String`.

Comment: @Kooilnc: Yeah that's what I meant. There's no need to stringy it as it's already parsed and can be accessed the way OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly stringifying the returned data and then treat that (string) as object. Here's a simple generic snippet printing all keys and values of the returned data.

```js
github();

function github() {
  const responseContainer = document.querySelector("#resp");
  fetch('https://api.github.com/users/KrunalLathiya')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      Object.entries(data).forEach( ([key, value]) => 
        responseContainer.textContent += `${key}: ${value}\n`
      )  
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

```html
<pre id="resp"></pre>
```